# how to create a grub2 efi usb drive that boots dos?

Tags: uefi, grub2, efi

I have an EFI only tablet and I want to be able to boot into dos. I don't want to use vmware or virtual box.
How can I install grub2 efi into usb flash drive and after that how can I add a dos to it?

Comment: AFAIK, DOS requires BIOS to boot, so it's not possible to do what you want unless the EFI has a Compatibility Support Module (CSM) to provide BIOS compatibility. My understanding is that most EFI-based tablets lack CSMs. Thus, chances are your only way of running DOS on your tablet is via a vritualization tool like VMWare or VirtualBox.